# Can I reuse Linux Mint bootable USB install on another machine

Tags: system-installation, usb

Can I reuse the Linux Mint install I created on a boot-able USB through "Balena Etcher setup" (successfully and verified) on another machine or will I need to create a new boot-able install on a different USB drive

Comment: Welcome! This is less of the place to ask about mint, as it is not ubuntu related or as described at this topic: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and considered off-topic. It will also be easier for you to find mint-related answers at mint communities such as [Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/index.php?sid=377b28f98cba376a07a49f210d0e03b7)

Answer (score 1):

A USB drive is very flexible and can be re-used in several ways.

- You can use (re-use) a live USB drive many times and in many computers in order to 'Try Ubuntu' or some other Linux distro and to install the operating system to internal drives.
- You can overwrite your live USB drive in order to create a new live system with a system from another iso file, for example an Ubuntu iso file.
- If you want to re-use a live USB drive as a standard storage device, you can re-format it. You might succeed with several tools, but some tools are confused by the partition table and file system of the live drive. In that case it can help to use mkusb in order to 'restore the drive to a standard storage device'.

  See this link: [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/post)